# How to view a 'private' file uploaded to S3 using the AWS JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I uploaded a file to S3 using the example here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node#direct-uploading

I changed the ACL from 'public-read' to 'private'.

Now since I required a signed url to upload the file, I imagine I would need a signed url to "Get" the file. How do I do that using node.js and the javascript sdk.... Is there a code example ?

Comment: I think you might find what you want here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html

Comment: @ElmerDantas Thanks Elmer, but thats an enormous amount of material to poke through. Is there a specific section that you think will answer the question.

Comment: As you mentioned ACL, I think in [this section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGETacl.html) will find something

Comment: @ElmerDantas Thanks Elmer, but if you read through that page, it really isn't relevant to the problem I am trying to solve. I am trying to figure out how to make a request to read a "private" file.

Comment: Oh...sorry! I've ready "Managing ACLs Using the REST API" and thought that will give you some relevant information. Unfortunately I cannot do more right now. Hope that you manage to solve. Regards

Comment: You use [`getSignedUrl`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property).